# Copy active row to another sheet with last row first empty cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 3 sheets. Example, my main data is in `Sheet1` if I input a data on Row 14 which is the ACTIVEROW then in that column let says `D14`, contains "N/A" or "1" value I want to copy that whole row data and paste to `Sheet2` ELSE it paste on `Sheet3` to the lastrow first empty cell.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHAvv.jpg)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CWqKF6Ta7_Tdtzzx47z7TZjzdGWPmi_tFbsRtdEWU3k/edit#gid=2100307022

Sorry for the lack of information. I provide an example of sheet or image above for additional info. Example, I want to input new data in  Sheet 1 if the value in the cell is "Male" copy the whole row and paste it to the Sheet!Male else if the value is "Female" it will paste it to the Sheet!Female.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Good day, I have 3 sheets. Example, my main data is in Sheet1 if I input a data on Row 14 which is the ACTIVEROW then in that column let says D14, contains "N/A" or "1" value I want to copy that whole row data and paste to Sheet2 ELSE it paste on Sheet3 to the lastrow first empty cell.`. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your expected result? By the way, when you show your current script, it will help users think of a solution.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, provide a practical example and folks will help you!

Comment: @Tanaike 
enter image description here

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CWqKF6Ta7_Tdtzzx47z7TZjzdGWPmi_tFbsRtdEWU3k/edit#gid=2100307022

Sorry for the lack of information. I provide an example of sheet or image above for additional info. Example, I want to input new data in Sheet 1 if the value in the cell is "Male" copy the whole row and paste it to the Sheet!Male else if the value is "Female" it will paste it to the Sheet!Female.

Comment: @onit https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHAvv.jpg

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CWqKF6Ta7_Tdtzzx47z7TZjzdGWPmi_tFbsRtdEWU3k/edit#gid=2100307022

Sorry for the lack of information. I provide an example of sheet or image above for additional info. Example, I want to input new data in Sheet 1 if the value in the cell is "Male" copy the whole row and paste it to the Sheet!Male else if the value is "Female" it will paste it to the Sheet!Female.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 14) {
    let vs = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    if(e.value == "N/A" || e.value == 1) {
      let dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
      dsh.getRange(r.range.rowStart,1,1,vs[0].length).setValues(vs)
    } else {
      let dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
      dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: AAMOI, there are a multitude of precedents for this question; why answer when there are so many duplicates?

Comment: @Tedinoz https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHAvv.jpg 

Sorry for the lack of information. I provide an example of sheet or image above for additional info. Example, I want to input new data in Sheet 1 if the value in the cell is "Male" copy the whole row and paste it to the Sheet!Male else if the value is "Female" it will paste it to the Sheet!Female.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for the response. in this statement 
if(sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 14)

It is just basing only on the row 14? or from Row 14 to the lastrow?

Comment: No.  it requires an edit in Column 14

Comment: @Cooper Hi, I've just tried your script and it works fine but I just want to copy only that row where I've input my new data, not all the data in the Sheet1

Comment: It's just copying one row

Comment: @Cooper Hi, can you try it here?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CWqKF6Ta7_Tdtzzx47z7TZjzdGWPmi_tFbsRtdEWU3k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Cooper the criteria is base on GENDER column . If the value is input "Male" it will copy the row and paste it to the "Male" Sheet elseif "Female" it will paste it on the "Female" Sheet. Thank you so much

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow links to spreadsheets.  Presumably we are all programmers here, so you should be able to copy and paste code and get it to run

Comment: So change the column as you require

Comment: It wasn't that way yesterday.  I'm not your flunky programming employee.  If you make changes to your question after answers are already provided then be prepared to make those changes youself.